# Typing a function that conditionally returns either a function or a number

Tags: typescript, types

I'm currently working on a codebase and trying to reduce the amount of any's that are in our code.

I've found a function that I'm having trouble with the best way to type it, or whether it even makes sense to keep it as-is. The function seems to be doing this:

https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/UtilityMethods/mapRange()

```
const conditionalReturn = (value?: number, func?: any) => value || value === 0 ? func(value) : func
```

This is used in a mapRange function:

```
const mapRange = (inMin:number, inMax: number, outMin: number, outMax: number, value?: number) => {
    const inRange = inMax - inMin;
    const outRange = outMax - outMin;
    return conditionalReturn(value, (value: any) => outMin + ((((value - inMin) / inRange) * outRange) || 0));
}

export const mapLengthToWidth = (inMin: number, inOut: number, outMin: number, outMax: number) => {
    const mapFn = mapRange(inMin, inOut, outMin, outMax);
    return (text: string): number => mapFn(text.length);
};

const conditionalReturn = (value?: number, func?: any) => value || value === 0 ? func(value) : func
```

I tried something basic like

`type sampleReturn = (value?: number) => number || ((x: number | string) => number)`

but that doesn't seem to work as I only return a function if a value isn't defined.

Code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4CUFgOYFMYF4YAUAlmALIkBcYArnAEZYBOANDCaQgB4Uw31OsQ1KOTA8+DFjCEiu42pNYA3BABtqWAPzz+jAJR4AfDADeAKBiWYoSLBJpMOfOy4wAtGzIkA3Bas3oaWEHbDwg2U53cNFfKxhGLChqRjBrcAATIigicDUUROSwAhV1LFZitQ0edABPA1xjGVEYAGpCAg6SjSj2EgMAek8QrAMAKnDhgwAfKZgABj09XwBfMzMsTiQQRlgA2EQkABksTCgACwAVEAB1InTzsOIvMV4FAU8AeWEdRWjKV90gmEHG4AMk9WM5jie3gyAAYql8Adhk9RKwSF8oECRCRsSCln5LAkkilCFANlAeNBGCQMHofkwjLCkAiCOTOFAAHSqE4Yc4E5a+MwwmyZbK5VT5EmIwhdLQMqQAM2oYGA2hgtQhMDlMBm2sqTlw+DmME0MGVqoqpQMPAtwDW-UGGwQcCQPJg1AgWGF4EC2Cgt3uZzCB2Op0uNzu5wIAEZWABmOasGMADiTMETCyFQA)

My attempt at it is to make it a little more simple, like so:

```
export const mapRange = (
  inMin: number,
  inMax: number,
  outMin: number,
  outMax: number,
  value?: number | string
) => {
  const inRange = inMax - inMin;
  const outRange = outMax - outMin;
  const mapRangeFunc = (value: number) => {
    return outMin + (((value - inMin) / inRange) * outRange || 0);
  };

  const valueAsInt = Number(value);

  if (value == undefined || Number.isNaN(valueAsInt)) return mapRangeFunc;

  return mapRangeFunc(valueAsInt);
};

export const mapLengthToWidth = (
  inMin: number,
  inOut: number,
  outMin: number,
  outMax: number
) => {
  const mapFn = mapRange(inMin, inOut, outMin, outMax);
  if (typeof mapFn !== 'function') return;
  return (text: string): number => mapFn(text.length);
};
```

Comment: The definition of the function feels funky to me: what happens if `value` _and_ `func` are undefined?

Comment: Hi, yeah it feels funky to me too. This is code before I started on the codebase, I'm just trying to improve it a little. As part of the process I was going to make `func` required and reorder the parameters.

Comment: Could you fix any typos in your code and make sure it's a [mre] so that others can easily work on it?  If you haven't passed it through an IDE after any modifications you've made then you might want to do so

Comment: Sure, I've updated the original comment.

Comment: External links to IDEs are nice supplements but the code should be in plaintext in the question itself as well.  (My IDE comment before was asking for you to make sure that your code didn't have typos before posting it; I was not asking for a link to an IDE)

Comment: Apologies, I cleaned up the code but didn't paste it back in.

Comment: So I think this sort of code is going to be hard to type in a way that the compiler follows; TypeScript isn't really good at understanding logic around conditional return types.  You can use overloads, you can use generics with conditional types, but neither of those are verifiably type safe since the compiler mostly gives up.  Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDe78m) shows some of the approaches but at some point you'll need to use loose typing or completely refactor